# How to work with problems correlated subqueries that reference other tables, without using Join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to work on public dataset `bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime` of the BigQuery. My goal is to get the output as three column that shows the 
discription(of the crime), count of them, and top district for that particular description(crime).

I am able to get the first two columns with this query.

```
  select 
    a.description, 
    count(*) as district_count
    from `bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime` a
  group by description order by district_count desc
```

and was hoping I can get that done with one query and then I tried this in order to get the third column showing me the Top district for that particular description (crime) by adding the code below

```
select 
  a.description, 
  count(*) as district_count,

       (
        select district from 
        (  select 
           district, rank() over(order by COUNT(*) desc) as rank
           FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime` 
           where description = a.description
           group by district 
        )  where rank = 1

  ) as top_District

  from `bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime` a
  group by description 
  order by district_count desc
```

The error i am getting is this. "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN."

I think i can do that by joins. Can someone has better solution possibly to do that using without join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT description, 
  ANY_VALUE(district_count) AS district_count, 
  STRING_AGG(district ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1) AS top_district
FROM (
  SELECT description, district,
    COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY description) AS district_count,
    COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY description, district) AS cnt
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime`
)
GROUP BY description
-- ORDER BY district_count DESC
```

Comment: did you have chance to try? does it work for you? it should!

Comment: Yes thanks Alot it does, got busy and didn't got time to accept this.

Comment: nope, that is actually district_count for respective description